# Managing parameter dependencies in Python 3 classes using constructors

Tags: python, class, constructor, dependencies

I'm setting up some hydraulic calculation scripts and plan on using them a lot in the future.  In short, I would like to have class methods that update the object in full when updating a single parameter.  Is my first pass method even viable, and what is the most pythonic way to rebuild an object based on a new parameter?

```
class Conduit(object):
    """
    Defines a Conduit through a set of knowns. All internals are kept
    in metric.
    """

    def __init__(self, b=0, n=0, S=0, y=0, Q=0, V=0):
        self.b = float(b)
        self.n = float(n)
        self.S = float(S)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.Q = float(Q)
        self.V = float(V)
        self.A = self._A()
        self.V = self._V()
        self.Q = self._Q()

    def set_width(self, b):
        self.__init__(b=b, y=self.y, n=self.n, S=self.S, Q=self.Q, V=self.V)

    def set_depth(self, y):
        self.__init__(b=self.b, y=y, n=self.n, S=self.S, Q=self.Q, V=self.V)

    def set_flow_rate(self, Q):
        self.__init__(b=self.b, y=self.y, n=self.n, S=self.S, Q=Q, V=self.V)

    def set_slope(self, S):
        self.__init__(b=self.b, y=self.y, n=self.n, S=S, Q=self.Q, V=self.V)

    def set_n(self, n):
        self.__init__(b=self.b, y=self.y, n=n, S=self.S, Q=self.Q, V=self.V)

    def _A(self):
        if self.b and self.y:
            return self.b * self.y
        elif self.Q and self.V:
            return self.Q / self.V

    def _V(self):
        if self.V:
            return self.V
        elif self.Q and self.y and self.b:
            return self.Q / (self.y * self.b)

    def _Q(self):
        if self.Q:
            return self.Q
        elif self.V and self.y and self.B:
            return self.V * self.y * self.b

    def Froude(self):
        if self.V and self.y:
            return self.V / sqrt(9.814 * self.y)
        elif self.Q and self.y and self.b:
            return (self.Q / (self.y * self.B)) / sqrt(9.814 * self.y)
```

I'm simply calling the initialization function inside of the set_x functions to resolve dependencies.  I see no reason why this wouldn't work, but I'm not sure about the internals of using a magic method in this way.  Should I create a rebuild method for this purpose?  Or should I create a new instance of the object and pass that new object to self?  The latter two options seem viable, but inefficient compared to calling an already existing function that does what I want.

Comment: It is not pythonic to write explicit setters and you shouldn't call the `__init__()` method. You should look at [this](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) example which explains how to use the `@property` decorator, which , I thinnk, is what you are looking for

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for and couldn't get via Google-fu.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Resolved in comments**:
>
> It is not pythonic to write explicit `setters` and you shouldn't call the `__init__() method`.
>
> You should look at [this](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) example which explains how to use the @property decorator,
>   which , I thinnk, is what you are looking for – gionni
>
> Exactly what I was looking for and couldn't get via Google-fu. Thanks!